# Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that if $|f'(x)| ≤ C<1$, then $f$ has at most one fixed point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, fixed-point-theorems

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that: if $|f'(x)| ≤ C < 1$ $\forall x$, then $f(x) = x$ 
>   has at  most one solution.

So using the Mean Value Theorem I know that
$$-1<-C\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leq C<1$$

I can do some manipulation with this inequality, but I am confused what "at most one solution" means. Obviously, the derivative of $f(x)=x$ is $1$ which doesn't hold for the inequality presented in the problem?

Any clarification/ hints would be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Note that "$f(x)=x$" here is _not_ a definition of the function $f$, but merely an equation that may or may not be true for any given value of $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Say $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$. Then the difference quotient $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ equals $1$, contradicting the inequality from MVT.